# Constraint solve inferred type's in order to refactor Java code

Tags: java, refactoring, constraints, rascal

We created a java test project, which has a arraylist.

```
private ArrayList mainList; 

public void AddTest(int number)
{   
    Test t = new Test();
    mainList.add(t);
    mainList.add(number);
}
```

As can be seen we add a integer and something of class Test. 
In rascal we create a object flow graph which consists of the following:

```
OFG: {
  <|java+class:///java/util/ArrayList/this|,|java+constructor:///java/util/ArrayList/ArrayList()|>,
  <|java+variable:///test1/Main/AddTest(int)/t|,|java+field:///test1/Main/mainList|>,
  <|java+class:///test1/Main/this|,|java+constructor:///test1/Main/Main()|>,
  <|java+parameter:///test1/Main/AddTest(int)/scope(number)/scope(0)/number|,|java+field:///test1/Main/mainList|>,
  <|java+class:///test1/Test/this|,|java+constructor:///test1/Test/Test()|>,
  <|java+class:///test1/Test/this|,|java+field:///test1/Main/mainList|>
}
```

As can be seen in the OFG a integer and Test get added to the mainList. Using this knowledge we want to indicate that ArrayList should contain type Object thus 
`private ArrayList mainList` -> `private ArrayList<Object> mainList`

For this we need a constraint solver which find the lowest type or generalization. Therefore we want to augment the solve function of the following propagation method

```
rel[loc,&T] propagate(OFG g, rel[loc,&T] gen, rel[loc,&T] kill, bool back) {
  rel[loc,&T] IN = { };
  rel[loc,&T] OUT = gen + (IN - kill);
  gi = g<to,from>; 
  set[loc] pred(loc n) = gi[n];
  set[loc] succ(loc n) = g[n];

  solve (IN, OUT) {
    IN = { <n,\o> | n <- carrier(g), p <- (back ? pred(n) : succ(n)), \o <- OUT[p] };
    OUT = gen + (IN - kill);    
  }

  return OUT;
}
```

However, we find it difficult to start this using Rascal 
We have experience with IBM ILOG, so constraint programming is not new.

Comment: Is the starting point, looking up the types in the OFG usend M3@typeDependency and then start solving?

Answer (score 1):

One idea, you could write another function or group of functions which relate type parameter positions to possible or necessary types:

- a many-to-many `rel[loc typeparameter, TypeSymbol bound` could encode of which types the type parameter should at least be a subtype according to the objects which flow into it according to your flow analysis.
- then an algorithm which computes a tight upperbound based on the alternatives, would combine several supertypes for the same typeparameter and compute the least type which includes them all. This algorithm would make the `rel[loc typeparameter, TypeSymbol bound]` smaller and smaller until only one solution remains for every type parameter.

  - You could use the `extends` and `implements` relations in the M3 model to find out about common super types, but you should also build in some knowledge about the Java type system, such as the fact the `java.lang.Object` is the top type for both classes and interfaces in Java, that classes have single inheritance and interfaces multiple inheritance.

TypeSymbol can be found in `lang::java::m3::TypeSymbol`